# custom tableView populated from CoreData, gives extra white cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So I have a problem when populating my tableviewcells from CoreData. It adds extra white cells before my real data is populated into the cells.

> - blank
> - blank
> - blank
> - firstname1 lastname1
> - firstname2 lastname2
> - firstname3 lastname3

Above is a examaple of how the tableview looks like.

The app is first downloading data from JSON and then put that information into CoreData and then populate the tableview from the `CoreData` and not JSON. 
Below is the code `viewController.swift`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var people: [NSManagedObject] = []
var involvedJSON = [InvolvedJSON]()

final let JSONUrl = URL(string: "http://JSON_URL")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        downloadJson()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "InvolvedOnline")

    do {
        people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func downloadJson(){
    guard let downloadURL = JSONUrl else {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in

        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print ("Something is wrong")
            return
        }
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloadedInvolved = try decoder.decode([InvolvedJSON].self, from: data)
            self.involvedJSON = downloadedInvolved
            for i in 0 ..< downloadedInvolved.count{
                let wristband_uid = downloadedInvolved[i].wristband_uid
                let security_id = downloadedInvolved[i].security_id
                let firstname = downloadedInvolved[i].firstname
                let lastname = downloadedInvolved[i].lastname
                let gender = downloadedInvolved[i].gender
                let priority = downloadedInvolved[i].priority
                let status = downloadedInvolved[i].status
                let creator_id = downloadedInvolved[i].creator_id
                let created_millis = downloadedInvolved[i].created_millis
                let priority_millis = downloadedInvolved[i].priority_millis
                let created_time = downloadedInvolved[i].created_time
                let priority_time = downloadedInvolved[i].priority_time

                // SAVE DATA to DATACORE InvolvedOnline
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.overwriteMergePolicyType)
                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "InvolvedOnline", in: context)
                let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

                item.setValue(wristband_uid, forKey: "wristband_uid")
                item.setValue(security_id, forKey: "security_id")
                item.setValue(firstname, forKey: "firstname")
                item.setValue(lastname, forKey: "lastname")
                item.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
                item.setValue(priority, forKey: "priority")
                item.setValue(status, forKey: "status")
                item.setValue(creator_id, forKey: "creator_id")
                item.setValue(created_millis, forKey: "created_millis")
                item.setValue(priority_millis, forKey: "priority_millis")
                item.setValue(created_time, forKey: "created_time")
                item.setValue(priority_time, forKey: "priority_time")
                do {
                    try context.save()
                    //print("saving success")
                    self.people.append(item)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed saving")
                }

            }

        }
        } catch {

        }
        }.resume()

}




}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let per = people[indexPath.row]

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InvolvedCell", for: indexPath) as? InvolvedCell else { return UITableViewCell()}

    cell.nameLbl.text = per.value(forKeyPath: "firstname") as? String
    cell.secidLbl.text = per.value(forKeyPath: "security_id") as? String
    cell.priorityLbl.text = per.value(forKeyPath: "priority") as? String
    cell.priorityTimeLbl.text = per.value(forKeyPath: "priority_time") as? String

    return cell
    }
}
```

And below is my InvolvedCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class InvolvedCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secidLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priorityLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priorityTimeLbl: UILabel!

}
```

If I remove `self.tableView.reloadData()` after the JSON has been saved into CoreData the white cells disapears. But then when i scroll in the application, the cells that gets put offscreen gets removed. This is my first attempt of doing an IOS app, Im trying to replicate some of my android apps. Btw, the extra white cells are not "data" from CoreData, when printing all rows from CoreData its looks correct in the log.

Comment: How much people.count returns? and how much people count in DB?

Comment: people.count returns 23. and when fetching all rows from database i get all 23 rows printed out. the blank cells are also always the same amount as people.count.

Comment: i found in my log futher down, that people.count keeps countin to 46. so im guessing that the view is called twice. and one of the times he prints blank cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i used wrong mergepolicy.

i had:

```
context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.overwrightMergePolicyType)
```

changed to:

```
context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
```

that removes the empty cells =)

Answer (score 0):

Try with your custom dataSource instead of [NSManagedObject].it may help you.